# Tracking Controls via an Array

Tags: vb.net

so I have an array that holds picture boxes. Can someone help me in coding a much, much more efficient way in assigning each index? I just can't figure it out.

```
    ArrayBullets(0) = picBullet0
    ArrayBullets(1) = picBullet1
    ArrayBullets(2) = picBullet2
    ArrayBullets(3) = picBullet3
    ArrayBullets(4) = picBullet4
    ArrayBullets(5) = picBullet5
    ArrayBullets(6) = picBullet6
    ArrayBullets(7) = picBullet7
    ArrayBullets(8) = picBullet8
    ArrayBullets(9) = picBullet9
    ArrayBullets(10) = picBullet10
    ArrayBullets(11) = picBullet11
    ArrayBullets(12) = picBullet12
    ArrayBullets(13) = picBullet13
    ArrayBullets(14) = picBullet14
    ArrayBullets(15) = picBullet15
    ArrayBullets(16) = picBullet16
    ArrayBullets(17) = picBullet17
    ArrayBullets(18) = picBullet18
    ArrayBullets(19) = picBullet19
    ArrayBullets(20) = picBullet20
    ArrayBullets(21) = picBullet21
    ArrayBullets(22) = picBullet22
    ArrayBullets(23) = picBullet23
    ArrayBullets(24) = picBullet24
    ArrayBullets(25) = picBullet25
    ArrayBullets(26) = picBullet26
    ArrayBullets(27) = picBullet27
    ArrayBullets(28) = picBullet28
    ArrayBullets(29) = picBullet29
```

It would be much appreciated.

Comment: What type is `picBullet` and are all picBullet's in the same container?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set an array to a list of values in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602405/how-to-set-an-array-to-a-list-of-values-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is generally no reason at all to do this.  They can always be found in the `Controls Collection` (you will not find them among `Components`).  Though it looks ordered, your list is actually a bit arbitrary; they will always be in the Controls Collection in ZOrder which starts as the order added to the Designer and may or may not matter.

If you need a way to track them, rather than storing a reference, you can use a `List(Of String)` to store their names to use to reference them in the controls collection.  If a control reference is somehow important, then a `List(Of PictureBox)` could be used instead.

```
Private myPicBoxes As New List(of String)
```

Method One - add names in Form Load:

```
For n As Integer = 0 To 29
    myPicBoxes.Add(String.Format("picBullet{0}", n.ToString))
Next n
```

Method Two - get names from controls in Form Load

```
For Each pb As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)
    mypicBoxes.Add(pb.Name)
Next
```

To do something with a particular PB:

```
Me.Controls( myPicBoxes( mypicBoxes(theIndex) ) ).Image = FileName
```

Clear all images:

```
For Each pbName As String in myPicBoxes
    Me.Controls(pbName).Image = Nothing
Next 

' or
For n As Integer = 0 To myPicBoxes.Count - 1
    Me.Controls(myPicBoxes(n)).Image = Nothing
Next n
```

If they are dynamic (you remove or add PictureBoxes at runtime) add/remove to your List as well:

```
Dim pb As New PictureBox
... set props
pb.Name = whatever you want

myPicBoxes.Add(pb.Name)
Me.Controls.Add(pb)
```

Removing:

```
Me.Controls.Remove( mypicBoxes(n))
mypicBoxes.RemoveAt(n)             ' also remove the name from your tracker
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the form designer designer to create your UI, populating the array manually really is the simplest and probably the best option.

You could iterate over `Controls` to find all the `PictureBox`es and put them into an array; but that won't have a guaranteed sort order because the designer loves to rearrange its code every times you change something.